# Kitten is too thin - what can I do?

Tags: cats, health, parasites, weight

I've got two kittens, a generic black kitten and a white Siamese kitten. I've got the black one about two months ago, the white one about a month ago. I don't know the exact ages but they were both young kittens, around the normal age for giving them away.

The white one is way too thin. The vet will do a parasite test as soon as I get some poop.She is also trying to suckle from the black one (definite behavior, no room for mistake). Maybe she was weaned early.

Any tips on how to fatten up the white one?

Comment: you need to give more information about the age is the cat 1 month 10 month old,what type of food do you give,are the cats indoor only or are they outdoor cats.there is no need to take a poop test just treat your cats for parasites most cats have them from tim to time.

Comment: You cold try making one onf the many variations on [Kitten Glop](https://www.google.com/search?ei=gZBQW4TCDNDW5gLN8ofQDA&q=kitten+glop&oq=kitten+glop&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i71k1l8.0.0.0.14478.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1..64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.inBnR_JfkFE) (in my experience they rally dive into the goat's milk one) or any high-calorie food which she really enjoys. Even store-bought 'KMR' or similar kitten milk-replacer formula should help.

Answer (score 2):

You should ask your vet for possible age of your kittens. It's possible to get it more or less accurately by teeth development and such. Then your course of action will depend on the age of your kitten.

If she was really weaned way too early you'll have to discuss giving her pro-/prebiotics and possibly immunity boosters with your vet. The diet is also something you should discuss with your vet, and it also depends on exact age.

In any case, young kittens should eat often and in small portions. If she's a hungry baby, keep track of how much she can eat at a time without getting sick and don't give her more -- no food will do any good if she pukes it right back. If she manages her portions well enough, give her as much as she wants. If she's under 3 months old she should eat at least 5-6 times a day. 3-5 months old -- 4-5 times a day. 5-9 months old (unlikely considering what you've posted but still) -- 3-4 times a day. 9-12 months old -- 3 times a day.

Comment: Uh.... I've never given food to cats in meals. They are just there on the plate, if I see the bottom of the plate I add more.

Comment: @Censoredtoprotecttheguilty So you're free feeding them. It might or might not cause a few problems in the long run but it's your choice. Then take note how often your younger kitten goes to eat and how much she eats. And if she's sick withing about an hour after eating.

Comment: @Censoredtoprotecttheguilty Also, if you're just leaving the food there I'm assuming you're feeding your cats dry because canned wouldn't last more than a few hours, and raw would go bad within an hour or two. Dry is not the best primary food for a very young kitten tbh.